# Send Id to another component after signin user react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I used Firebase for user authentication. I set functions for register users. then I created a signin function. When the user signs user redirects to user profile edit mode. Now I want to retrieve data when signing in user his/her particular data. I need to get a firebase user id to pass the another component when sign in. I try to get firebase user id and pass id to another component.Then I try to pass id to the backend using get function. Then I think i can retrive data for paticular user

signin function

```
async onSubmit(e) {

e.preventDefault();

const email = this.state.todo_email;
const password = this.state.todo_password;

try {
  const signInresponse = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  history.push('/User/Directory');
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
I may have misread your question

Your `signInresponse` should return a `UserCredential` which has a `user` property. The user prop can then be used to grab a [bunch of other props](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User).
So, `signInresponse.user.uid` will get you the uid...
I personally like the Promise structure and I destructure the user out, because it feels more event-driven.

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(({ user }) => {
    // do stuff 
    setUID(user.uid);
    setUserName(user.displayName);
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    handleWarning(error);
   });
```

As an aside, check out the [react-firebase-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hooks). It can make things a little cleaner.

I hope this better answers your question.

---

You could use `React.Context` as a hook and expose it to your app as need. The usage is exactly like the `useState()` hook.

The main Context hook can be in a file:

```
// UserContext.js
import { createContext } from "react";

const userContextProvider = createContext({
  userContext: {
    name: null,
    uid: null,
  },
  setUserContext: () => {},
});

export default userContextProvider;
```

In your base-level App you import the hook above, and wrap your project:

```
// App.js
import userContextProvider from "./api/UserContext";
const [userContext, setUserContext] = useState({ name: null, uid: null });
const value = { userContext, setUserContext };

return (
  <userContextProvider.Provider value={value}>
    <Router>
      <Route path={} component={} ...
// ...
```

And then in the components you want to set or read your uid or name or whatever value:

```
// RandomComponent.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import userContextProvider from "./api/UserContext";

const { userContext, setUserContext } = useContext(userContextProvider);
```

Then you can use `userContext` as your getter and `setUserContext` as your setter just like `useState()`

Comment: Thankyou for answer.but how i get firebase user id when user loging